# How to clear the Text on Clear button using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a clear button that needs to clear the TextBox value(that is entered) on this button click using JQuery function.

Comment: @Rita, if you find one of these answers answered your question then you should mark it as the answer.  It helps others when they look at this question later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to attach a click event to the button that will set the value of the input element to empty.

```
$("#clearButton").click(function() {
        $("#textbox1").val("");
});
```

Of course to give you exact selectors we need to see the actual html.  The above jquery call would work for this html.

```
<button type="button" id="clearButton">Clear</button>
<input id="textbox1" type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#' + fieldName).val("");
```

or you can use a class name like;

```
$('.' + fieldName).val("");
```

Class names are better sometimes when id's are changed in the environment.

Comment: Don't you mean textbox name, and onclick?

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a "thingtoclear" and a "thingtoclick" then you might want something like this:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
       $('#thingtoclick').click( function () {
             $('#thingtoclear').val(""); 
       });
     });
```